# Macro expansion inside NSString

Tags: objective-c, macros

How can I expand a macro inside NSString? I've got the following code:

```
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 2000

NSString *alertTxt = @"Your message exceeded MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH characters";
```

As you can predict I get "Your message exceeded MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH characters" instead of "Your message exceeded 2000 characters".
Is there a way to get my MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH expanded in the string?

Comment: There are various obscure C macro coding techniques that would probably work, but Joe's approach is much more straight-forward and less error-prone.

Comment: That's right. I was just wondering about macro expansion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSStrings works like C strings. I.e. you can concatenate string constants by writing them next to each other.

```
/* nested macro to get the value of the macro, not the macro name */
#define MACRO_VALUE_TO_STRING_( m ) #m
#define MACRO_VALUE_TO_STRING( m ) MACRO_VALUE_TO_STRING_( m )

#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 2000
NSString *alertTxt = @"Your message exceeded "
                      MACRO_VALUE_TO_STRING(MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
                      " characters";
```

Comment: Good one, unfortunately it truncates strings that contain // for some reason, as in URLs -- probably parses the rest as C comment

Comment: Yes, I think you need to define the macro value as a string with quotation marks and then skip using `MACRO_VALUE_TO_STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringWithFormat:` like this:

`NSString *alertTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your message exceeded %i characters", MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];`

This uses the same placeholders `%@`, `%i`, etc. as NSLog.

Comment: You are assuming a macro with numerical value